# Rails: Joining the same table twice and querying a joined attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Rails app that parses price information from a variety of sources. The models look something like this:

```
class Price
  attr_accessor :value
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :added_pricelist, :class_name => "Scrape"
  belongs_to :removed_pricelist, :class_name => "Scrape"
end

class Product
  attr_accessor :name
end

class PriceList
  attr_accessor :created_at
  has_many :prices
end
```

Every day, a scraper runs, and parses some prices for products from an API. It creates a new PriceList every time the scraper is run. The scraper records which pricelist a price appeared (or disappeared) in - so the data might look like this.

```
# NB: Assume product_id is always 1 for these
{ value: 100, added_pricelist_id: 1, removed_pricelist_id: 2 }
{ value: 120, added_pricelist_id: 2, removed_pricelist_id: 3 }
{ value: 140, added_pricelist_id: 3, removed_pricelist_id: 4 }
```

A new object is only created when the price changes, so if it stayed the same, you'd just have:

```
{ value: 100, added_pricelist_id: 1, removed_pricelist_id: 4 }
```

My question is: Using ActiveRecord, how can I find the average price of a product for each of the last 30 days? I need to be able to find all the prices that were active on a particular day, and then average that number. Can that be done in a single query? (NB: This is with Postgres).

Feel free to get me to clarify anything that doesn't make any sense, and thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: I don't understand the example data. In the first cluster of 3, are those 3 example days? Or 3 entries for the same day? In the "stayed the same" example, what about that example demonstrates that something is staying the same? Why does an addition and removal happen even when something stays the same?

Comment: The first example is three days where the price changes each day. The second is where the price remains the same for three days. In both examples, the price disappears on day 4.

Answer (score 0):

**AVG**

Although I was a little confused with what you posted, hopefully I can give you some help:

You have at least two options:

> 1. [ActiveRecord `.average`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average)
> 2. [SQL AVG](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_avg.asp)

Both of these perform the same task (except one is ActiveRecord based), so I would look at firstly getting your SQL Query correct, and then performing the AVG function on the data you have

---

**Query**

> I need to be able to find all the prices that were active on a
>   particular day, and then average that number

I would do something like this:

```
#app/models/PriceList.rb
Class PriceList < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :today, -> { where(created_at: DateTime.now.at_beginning_of_day.utc..Time.now.utc).average(:value) } 
end
```

This would allow you to call `@product.pricelist.today`

Comment: So the `today` scope gives me today, but what I really want is to be able to get an average for each day in the past 30 days.